# 404 The requested URL could not be matched by routing

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-route

I'd just started to learn [zend-framework](/questions/tagged/zend-framework) and following this [user guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/index.html).

I'm able to successfully install the [**`zend skeleton application`**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html) and moved on to the [**`routing and controllers`**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html). But after completion of the tutorial I requested the url: `http://zf2-tutorial.localhost/album` in my browser and I'm getting **`404`**.

I'd looked down into the comments where some people saying about changes in

```
'route' => '/album[/][:action][/:id]'
```

needs to be

```
'route' => '/album[/:action][/:id]'
```

but that doesn't help either. Can anyone help me in resolving the issue?

**Directory structure:**

[image: zend application directory structure]

Comment: have you initialised your album module in your ``application.config.php``? all controller defined in ``module.config.php`` from your module?

Comment: yes.as mentioned [here in comments](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html#comment-1082208319)

Comment: post the error details, stack trace etc.

Comment: can you please update your code with the full module config from your album module

Comment: You say `I'm getting 404` but what's the *actual* error message that's being reported with the 404? `The requested URL could not be matched by routing` or `The requested controller was unable to dispatch the request` or is it something else?

Comment: `The requested URL could not be matched by routing`

Comment: the router config is fine, you might have some typos in your controller files, file structure is good... is ``/album`` the full url you trying to call?

Comment: yes. I'm calling this url `http://zf2-tutorial.localhost/album` as stated above

Comment: your virtual host document root is pointing to the zf ``public`` folder? in your ``AlbumController`` the function ``indexAction`` is present and namespace is correct? ``ModRewrite`` is enabled?

Comment: yes. my virtual host document points to `public` folder of **zf**. I'll update my question with `AlbumController`

Comment: ``ModRewrite`` is enabled on your server?

Comment: yes. I'd enabled it as `sudo a2enmod rewrite`. before that I was getting error **500**

Comment: have you set up a wildcard route in your application module config?

Comment: I don't know. How do I'm supposed to do that? This is the thing I currently have in `module.config.php` of my module(album) `'route' => '/album[/:action][/:id]',`

Comment: i just saw the new skelleton application...they fixed the wildcard route...so we can skip this...just to test all possibilities ...please  call ``die('here');`` right in the first line of your ``indexAction`` function and check the output by calling the uri

Comment: still same error. no output from `die`

Comment: ok now i would ask to upload all files ... normally this basic config must work...the only possibility just left is that you have somewhere a small typo

Comment: Instead of posting just the snippet you keep posting from your config, post the actual config, just because that line's right doesn't mean your config is.

Comment: ``AlbumController`` php tags present ? ``<?php``

Comment: @Crisp: I do not get your point.

Comment: @MohammadFaisal, my point is, you were asking people to 'guess' at what might be the problem, there was insufficient information for a diagnosis which has resulted in this extended discussion in the comments.

Comment: @Crisp: I'd just gone one step up after setting up [zend skeleton application](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html) and now I'm getting error. Till that point it was working as supposed to be. I'd already created a virtual host for that too. but my question is why `The requested URL could not be matched by routing`? as I'm doing exactly mentioned in there? I'd double checked and no typo there

Comment: you are actually supplying the module.config.php in your Module class's getConfig method?  http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/modules.html#setting-up-the-album-module

Comment: thanks a lot for the above link. The link they have skipped in there after http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

thanks to [Crisp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1112089/crisp) for mentioning the url in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758907/404-the-requested-url-could-not-be-matched-by-routing/22760520#comment34695703_22758907).

there is a [missing link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/modules.html) between [zend skeleton application](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html) and [routing and controllers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html) where the initial module structure and module file code is written.

the code in my `Module.php` was missing is

```
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;
class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface, ConfigProviderInterface {
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
     {
         return array(
             'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                 'namespaces' => array(
                     __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                 ),
             ),
         );
     }
    public function getConfig() {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a tutorial, better start from page 1 ;)

Comment: @Sam and where's the page 1?

Comment: after [this](http://framework.zend.com/learn/) I'd chosen [`getting started zend framework 2`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/overview.html). after that in the next pages, there's the missing link which I'd mentioned in my answer

Comment: You sir, are actually right, excuse me - idk what happened with the docs ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you set the Apache webserver to create a Virtual Host ([Learn how here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html))

Perhaps try going to `localhost/album` and see if that works, because by the information/routes given, this should work.