# fixing Zend2 Framework 404 error has now given me fatal error: ModuleEvent::setModuleName expects a string as an argument; integer provided'

Tags: php, zend-framework2

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception '`Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent::setModuleName expects a string as an argument; integer provided' in C:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zend-modulemanager\src\ModuleEvent.php on line 64***

I'm new to Zend and trying [the Skeleton application exercise](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html)

On attempting to load `http://zf2-tutorial.localhost/album` I was getting error

> 404 -"The requested URL could not be matched by routing".***

So I then followed [some suggestions on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758907/404-the-requested-url-could-not-be-matched-by-routing#_=_) and it seems to have messed things up altogether for me.

[One suggestion was to put `die('here');` in the `indexAction`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758907/404-the-requested-url-could-not-be-matched-by-routing#comment34694765_22758907) to see what error shows up.  So I tried it, got the above error and then deleted the same line again from `indexAction`.

However the same error persists and I am unable to resolve it. I'm using WAMP on Windows 8.

To try to resolve it I cleared the DNS cache, cleared browser history and cookies, restarted all services, rebooted, refreshed WAMP...but still the same. Any Ideas please?

Comment: Hey can you post a link to your module config? Thanks!

Comment: module.congig.php is

"return array(
     'controllers' => array(
         'invokables' => array(
             'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
         ),
     ),
     'view_manager' => array(
         'template_path_stack' => array(
             'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
         ),
     ),
 );"